# How to get element by xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am designing an scraper using python scrapy for the site

https://www.kimovil.com/de/wo-kaufen-oneplus-2-3gb-16gb-cn

I have extracted many elememt by expath but not able to get 
storage versionn of phone.

By inspecting element one can get the xpath but when try to call in scrapy shell it returns :

```
[]
```

Comment: i have tried using scrapy shell with the following                                                                       code executed:---response.xpath('//dl[@class="grouped-versions-list js_bands-versions"]/dd[1]/ul/li[@class="item"]/a/text()').extract()
output  getting :--    []

Comment: desired output :--  3GB 16GB

Answer (score 0):

Some facts:

- It's a large website, they have spent some time developing it, it's probably using modern technologies
- It's loading `https://www.kimovil.com/build/app-js.227fce30.js` which has `app` in its name and `build` in path

Judging by this they use some sort of JS frontend framework and the DOM is not complete when scrapy reaches the webpage. The data you are looking for is being loaded and DOM is being manipulated later in the lifecycle.

You can inspect requests your browser is making, one of them is this `https://www.kimovil.com/_json/oneplus-2-3gb-16gb-cn_prices_deals.json` for example.

Or you can use a scraping framework based on selenium or something else that can run javascript on page.

Comment: Its for the price but i dont want price , want to scrape version list when inspected  its under class=version list

Comment: either find where the data for the version list is coming from (another request) or use a browser automation based solution like I suggested (selenium etc)